# Pass value from one directive to another using function binding '&'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass a value from a parent directive to child directive. In this scenario parent directive has a function which needs to be executed on click on child directive's div and pass ng-model value from child directive to parent directive's calling function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12543/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('parentDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Parent directive</div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.someFunc = function(value) {
        alert(value);
      }
    }
  }
});
myApp.directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="data.name"><button ng-click="issue(data.name)">Child Directive</button>',
    scope: {
      issue: '&'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <parent-directive ng-transclude>
    <child-directive issue="someFunc()"></child-directive>
  </parent-directive>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12543/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/Lvc0u55v/12545/) with the right solution.

You need to specify the parameters when you bind the function in your parent directive.

```
<child-directive issue="someFunc(value)"></child-directive>
```

And pass an object with those parameters as keys in your child directive.

```
<button ng-click="issue({ value: data.name })">Child Directive</button>
```

Comment: Awsome!!

My bad i did not specify the parameters in the parent directive :(

But why do i have to pass the parameter as keys??

{ value: data.name} why only data.name did not work??

Comment: No worries. It's a pretty common error. And that's how AngularJS works.

Comment: Probably [this](http://www.codelord.net/2016/05/13/understanding-angulars-and-binding/) is a good article explaining why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

but still i did not understand why i need to pass an object? - I am being curious :D

If you can answer for me it would be really great or please tell me where should i look for an answer for this.